# Why my return array function won't using or combinning with "Math" methode after it has returnig to the array's values?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, return, return-value, spreadsheet

Guess ... I'm trying to write a function that returns an Array that I can pass into a String format. Like I will mention to here: I have the ***randomColor(customColorsArrays, takenColorsArray)*** the function is depend to class has filled which *if the both of them are empty return the value of color has calculated by Math methode*, *if the class of customColorsArrays has filled by user to put their own Array themeselves*, *if the both of class has writed by user means return the array's var* has seted at an earlier inside that function. To make this clearly see at the down below these of the codes :

```
function randomColor(customColorsArray, takenColorsArray) {
 var text = "",
     colors = ["orange", "yellow", "red", "maroon"];

   if (customColorsArray && takenColorsArray) {
      var text = "["+colors+"]";
   }
     else if (!customColorsArray && !takenColorsArray) {
      text += colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
   }
     else {
      text += customColorsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * customColorsArray.length)];
  };

   return text;
}

function personalRandomColor(e) {
 var text = "";

   if (e == "orange") {text += "almond";}
    else if (e == "yellow") {text += "melrose";}
    else if (e == "red") {text += "danube";}
    else if (e == "maroon") {text += "magenta";};

  return text;
}
```

*And this is the **HTML** code to implemented the function an above.*

```
bla... bla... bla...
  var customColorsArrays = randomColor('passingClass', 'takenColor'),
      randomFirstColor = randomColor(),
      skipFirstColors = customColorsArrays.replace('\[', '\[\"').replace('\]', '\"\]').replace(/[\,]/g, '\"\, \"').replace('\"'+randomColor()+'\"\,', ''),
      randomSecondColor = personalRandomColor(randomColor(toString(skipFirstColors))),
bla... bla... bla...
```

Comment: What's the *expected output*? And what is the *problem*? What works and what doesn't work?  See [mre]

Comment: @TheMaster ...   Why while I test to running the function from var of "randomSecondColor" such as: console.log(randomSecondColor);  the output isn't what I really expected what the cameout is a char is not the value of color ???

Comment: Hello @JamalLudin, could you please describe the idea of what are you trying to accomplish exactly? Maybe that way we can understand the question and help you. Thanks!!

Comment: @carlesgg97 ... I want to exactly pick the value from return of randomSecondColor which it must be color value not an char of output ...

Comment: `typeof customColorsArray` is `string` and not a `array`. Correct? `customColorsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * customColorsArray.length)];
  };` it's the same as ``"whatever"[1]``

Comment: Hello @jamalludin, your personalRandomColor(e) is not valid - what is `customColor1`? It is not defined anywhere in the snippet you provided. Also, the braces don't seem to match. Please take a look into that function and maybe then we can find a solution. Cheers

Comment: @TheMaster ...  Yup you are right. How to return it back to the an array for the result as an array not as an string after I pull them out to the **customColorsArray's var** then I _**use them back as an array to use it to another randomColor()**_ in "**personalRandomColor()**" as a var of "**randomSecondColor**" ???

Comment: @carlesgg97 ...  Yeah you're right carles that's because my mistake I've forget to remove before post it. I was updated it way.

Comment: Look into `JSON.parse()`. Your entire script is weak, because your variables switch between `string` type and `array` type and that'll cause multiple problems. Consider *rewriting* the entire script with attention to *types*. A variable declared should **not change type** during execution.

Comment: hey @jamalludin I think I have finally understood your question.. kindly let me know if the answer provided fixes your issue.. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy and straight forward way to fix your code is to replace the line

```js
randomSecondColor = personalRandomColor(randomColor(toString(skipFirstColors)))
```

for

```js
randomSecondColor = personalRandomColor(randomColor(JSON.parse(skipFirstColors)))
```

The reason for this is that `randomColor` takes arrays of elements, and you are passing a String to it. The argument, `skipFirstColors`, is a String which is in fact a JSON representation of a list of Strings. You want it to be an actual list, not a String representing a list.

The [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function will evaluate the String returned by skipFirstColors and return the list it represents.

Furthermore, I would suggest you revisit and potentially refactor your code. You should try to use the built-in types such as lists as function returns instead of working with JSON representations of your objects (serialized as Strings) as that will avoid this sort of errors, and will make for cleaner code.

Comment: Oh God thanks ...  Finally, you've answered my question with the clearly and definitely. Chould be this is one too what @TheMaster are trying to do to explainning to me too at since beginning thank you so much for both of you !!!  and the rest all of you too guess ...   Thanks one thousand more time ...

Comment: @jamalludin Glad to know it worked for you mate! :)

Comment: Oh hey ...  @carlesgg97 May I ask you one more time this is still an about what happened above! Why in my "**randomSecondColor**'s" var in sometime but not too often it just chould be over in several time it shows all items of an array even if I have put on the code to replace what has loaded in "**randomFirstColor**" and then so this will be make to **Skip of First Color**. ???

Comment: Sorry, it was solved by my self. I've just solved this with fix some regEx from class of .replace() lines that's to make it fixed.